# SoX How to add noise to a file?

Tags: noise, sox

I would like to ADD noise to audio files.  Is there a way to accomplish this in SoX (or other tool)?

I am performing machine learning research, and need to test my algorithms in the presence of noise.  Ideally, I would like to specify a signal to noise ratio and have noise added to reach that target SNR.

I know that I could generate a noise file and subsequently mix it with each of my source files.  As I need to do this in a batch mode over thousands of files, I seek simpler more elegant method.

Any ideas or suggestions most welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: There is no single SoX command, but some scripting could do it. Are you on Linux, OS X, Windows, …?

Comment: For this project, I am working on a windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and found this website particularly useful:

http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/plab/guestwiki/index.php?title=Sox_in_phonetic_research#Add_noise_to_an_audio_file

Answer (score 2):

Piping outputs gave me error. Instead, just write the noise on a file and then do the mixing:

`sox input.wav noise.wav synth whitenoise vol 0.02 && sox -m input.wav noise.wav noisyinput.wav`